# What is the maximum span.status.message size allowed?

Tags: google-cloud-trace

While experimenting with the v2 batchWrite API i was able to write status messages as long as 5KB. Does google enforce a maximum? 
Everything other trace field seems to be very tightly restricted to 128B/256B.

Comment: Can you provide more information such as API detail? What API you are using?

Comment: edited the question to include the API (v2 batchWrite)

Comment: You can write 5k to the message field. Are you asking about other fields or just this field? Are you able to send the request and just see if this is an issue about what you see in the result in cloud trace UI?

Comment: i'm asking about the Status.message field.
i tried 5k and confirm in the trace UI that it worked, but i'm looking for formal documentation about it.

Comment: At this time it is not publicly documented. I've filed an internal Feature Request to have it documented. This is a request through official means. Google will consider the need based on its feasibility, or the number of customers who ask for it, but I can't guarantee an implementation or provide you with an ETA for it.